# ComboBox.SelectedItem not working as expected C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, combobox

I have a combo box I added items to in the page load method and within a button click I am trying to set either the text that is typed or the item selected from the dropdown. I am using ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() which works when something is typed in but once the user selects something from dropdown the string is empty that is passed through.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page) == null)
            {
                Page.Form.Controls.AddAt(0, new ScriptManager());
            }

            DiffComboBoxUrls.Items.Add(XMLConstants.PolicyStoreApplications.Value1);
            DiffComboBoxUrls.Items.Add(XMLConstants.PolicyStoreApplications.Value2);
            DiffComboBoxUrls.Items.Add(XMLConstants.PolicyStoreApplications.Value3);
            DiffComboBoxUrls.Items.Add(XMLConstants.PolicyStoreApplications.Value4);
            DiffComboBoxUrls.Items.Add(XMLConstants.PolicyStoreApplications.Value5);
        }

 protected void ChangeAppSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string FOPath = FODirectory.Text;
            string PolicyStoreName = DiffComboBoxUrls.SelectedItem.ToString(); //this comes back as "" when an item is selected and works when something is typed in
         .....
}
```

Comment: I believe that the Viewstate field is the problem. Haven't done much of the asp for a long time but if you make a post request the information is gone unless you retain it in a view state field. Have a look a the basics of asp.net.

Comment: I think SelectedItem should have a Value member you should check. Not sure I remember right, though, and can't test it right now.

Comment: before SelectedItem Check SelectedIndex, and see its value

Comment: I'm not sure I am following these comments. When I debug through I can go in and see that there are items in the combobox but the selected index is -1

Comment: Found the problem! I moved the script manager line to my aspx page and it worked. Not entirely sure why